# tomcat https configuration using generated keystore file

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, https, keystore

Before I start, I just followede the steps from DZone.

[Setting Up Tomcal SSL in 5 Minutes](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes)

I have seen several similar tutorials, but I cannot find the answer to my problem.

**Problem:**

I can access HTTP/8080, but cannot access HTTPS/8443 and it seems to be loading forever.
Tried using HTTP/8443 which got an error (As I expected)

I tried using the curl command:

```
borgymanotoy@ujease:/home/borgymanotoy$ curl -Iv https://localhost:8443
* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:8443/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 697 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Operation timed out after 300495 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Operation timed out after 300495 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

**Note:**

I followed the steps in the given site. Checked the following:

1) Successfully generated the .keystore file.
2) Updated tomcat's server.xml properly with exact path of the generated keystore file with password, and checked the proper cases.
3) Checked tomcat logs and did not find any error.

Anyone tried following the steps in the link, got the error and fixed it?

Comment: keystoreFile="/Users/loiane/.keystore" - This line in the site. Have you added the exact keystore filename?

Comment: What happens if you try `openssl s_client -connect localhost:8443`?

Comment: @jorrin yes I have, keystoreFile="/home/borgymanotoy/.keystore"

Comment: Post your server.xml file. Ensure you do not have a firewall blocking 8443

Comment: <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" SSLEnabled="true" secure="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false" disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="150" keystoreFile="/home/borgymanotoy/.keystore" keystorePass="bilatsabaw" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" sslProtocol="TLS" />

Comment: yes... I already allowed the port 8443 (ufw allow 8443)

Comment: the tutorial you followed is rather old (2011) and refers to tomcat 7. I recommend following a more up to date guide e.g. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: Thanks! I will try that, I forgot that I am using tomcat 8.5 :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to nandsito for pointing to the latest tomcat guide.

By the way, I am using Tomcat 8.5, running on Ubuntu Linux.
The tutorial is using Tomcat 7, thus I have some connection issues.

I just set the SSL Connector Settings on my tomcat's server.xml file.

```
<!-- Define a SSL Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/home/borgymanotoy/.keystore" keystorePass="bilat-savore"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Restarted my tomcat, and tried the curl command:

```
$ curl -Iv https://localhost:8443

* Rebuilt URL to: https://localhost:8443/
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 694 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

I can now access https://localhost:8443/